# SMS is not sending

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, mobileconnect, encryption

I have ampscript to be used for mobile connect triggered in Journey Builder
The SMS does not send but when I replace with just plain text, it does.

Is there any errors with my code?

```
Test SMS via Journey. 

%%[
var @spc
set @len = length(AttributeValue('_SubscriberKey')
set @key = AttributeValue('_SubscriberKey')

if  @len == 4 then
set @spc = concat('########',@key)

elseif @len == 8 then
set @spc = concat('####',@key)

elseif @len == 10 then
set @spc = concat('##',@key)

else
set @spc = AttributeValue('_SubscriberKey')
endif

set @enc = Base64Encode(@spc)

]%%

Encrypted URL: http://cloud.e.mycomp.com/SGTestProfilePage?pk=%%=v(@enc)=%%
Plain Text: http://cloud.e.mycomp.com/SGTestProfilePage?sk=%%_SubscriberKey%%
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to provide some more information when you say the SMS does not send. Is it displaying an error? Is it sending a blank SMS text? Are you able to send a static SMS text?

Also it looks like you're using `Base64Encode` to encrypt values. `Base64Encode` is not very secure, I would use the `CloudPagesURL` function to pass data to your Cloud Page. You can access `_SubscriberKey` or `emailaddr` as first class strings and do not need to worry about Base 64 encoding which can be hacked.

```
%%=CloudPagesURL(ID, 'spc', @spc)=%%
```

CloudPageURL documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm